# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'price'

Tags: python-3.x, django

Добавил себе в проект приложение
https://github.com/DrMartiner/django-yandex-kassa
Реализовал вью, модель, сделал migrate

Получаю ошибку

```
Internal Server Error: /home/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vois/virtual_env/oi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vois/virtual_env/oi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/vois/virtual_env/oi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vois/virtual_env/oi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vois/virtual_env/oi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vois/virtual_env/oi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 150, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/home/vois/code/project/kassa/views.py", line 17, in get_context_data
    amount = count * item.price
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'price'
[30/Mar/2018 04:38:25] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 500 82767
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatechars
from yandex_kassa.utils import get_uuid

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Наименование', max_length=32)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField('Стоимость')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return truncatechars(self.name, 16)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товары'


class Order(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField('ID заказа', max_length=64,
                            default=get_uuid, primary_key=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey('kassa.Item', verbose_name='Товар', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField('Кол-во', default=1)
    payment = models.ForeignKey('yandex_kassa.Payment',
                                verbose_name='Платеж', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField('Сумма заказа')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Заказ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'
```

views.py

```
from random import randint
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from yandex_kassa.forms import PaymentForm
from .models import Item
from .models import Order
from yandex_kassa.models import Payment


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        count = randint(1, 3)
        item = Item.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
        amount = count * item.price

        payment = Payment(order_amount=amount)
        payment.save()

        order = Order(item=item, count=count,
                      amount=amount, payment=payment)
        order.save()

        ctx = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['order'] = order
        ctx['form'] = PaymentForm(initial=dict(orderNumber=order.uuid, sum=amount,
                                               customerNumber=payment.customer_number))
        return ctx


class OrderDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Order

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        try:
            return super(OrderDetailView, self).get_object(queryset)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            raise Http404
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки и относящийся к ней код.

Comment: Судя по логу, вы не заполнили базу, перед ее использованием.

Comment: `item = Item.objects.all().order_by('?').first()` возвращает `None`, то есть в базе нет ни одного объекта модели `Item`.